# Couldn't get the NSData

Tags: ios

I have this url, an audio file  http://www.metrixzolutions.com/audio/1353301873.caf   I check the url on browser, it's an audio data file.

However, when I do this

```
   NSString* Path;
Path=@"http://www.metrixzolutions.com/audio/1353301873.caf";
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:Path];
NSData *downloadData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
```

The downloadData is nil, and saying it's not a NSdata, why?

Answer (score 2):

Because this URL doesn't represent a filesystem path. Try using `NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:Path];` and it should be fine.

And next time please make the effort to read attentively the correspoding documentation.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get data from the web you can implement NSURLRequest and NSURLConnection.

```
NSString *path = @"http://www.metrixzolutions.com/audio/1353301873.caf";
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:path];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];


[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request
                 queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
                 completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {

    NSLog(@"%@", data); //<-- this is your data

}];
```

Comment: "you need to implement..." - you needn't, the error is not there.